# Where can I find kafka folder in mac for kafka-connect properties file?

Tags: macos, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to write my first kafka connect code. Most of the blogs state to put Kafka Connect specific files or project jars in the Kafka directory. I installed Kafka using brew, so having trouble finding the location and following the most of the KafkaConnect blogs.

Can someone please help where I should look for kafka directory in order to put Kafka Connect specific files?

I tried looking for the folder in /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/etc but couldn't find them. I'm running my zookeeper and local server from these locations.

I also tried finding through Finder, but couldn't get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `brew info apache-kafka` helps? Search your PATH? `which connect-standalone`...

You could search for it

```bash
find /etc -name connect-standalone.properties
find /usr -name connect-standalone.properties
find /usr -name kafka*.jar
```

Or you could always download Kafka separately from Homebrew and extract it where you know where it'll be...